# Server side mobile browser detection

Tags: java, http, networking, network-programming

Is there anyway to detect on the server side (on a Servlet, for example) if a HTTP request comes from a mobile browser, **with 100% accuracy**? Is this doable by only checking http headers regarding HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE, HEADER_HTTP_ACCEPT or the UA?

Edit: Please exclude security threats from your answers, such as spoofing of http requests. You dont need to take that into account.

Thanks

Comment: No; nothing is 100%.  Especially if the user clicks "Request desktop site".

Comment: you can always modify header to send, nothing is 100% but wurfl has good database and broader way to detect http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/njava_index.php

Comment: Any sort of HTTP request can be easily spoofed.

Comment: @SLaks Yeah I know, and as far as I know (100% sure), SO is not a philosophical forum...

Answer (score 0):

The common way is to check if the user-agent string matches the following regex:

```
/obile/
```

Comment: Well, my Android is always recognized as a mobile device by sites that care, and its browser UA does not include that string anywhere.

Comment: @Widdershins: In my defense, I didn't come up with this. This is just how it's commonly done. I, too, realize how wacky this really is :P

Comment: Haha yeah, it's an OK hack and will work for devices like iPhones (which typically include "Mobile" in their UA) but generally speaking you just have to have a really big list.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side mobile device detection in Java servlets is possible if you use solution from 51Degrees. 51Degrees documentation section contains a [complete set of instructions](http://51degrees.com/Support/Documentation/Java/Web-Applications/Extending-BaseServlet) from setting up new servlet to integrating device detection in to existing servlet.

To integrate device detection in to your servlet:

Download Java device detector from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fiftyone-java/files/). Extract files from archive. Add JARs from 'dist' and 'lib/webapp' directories to your project. Add import:

```
import fiftyone.mobile.detection.webapp.BaseServlet;
```

Change

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

To:

```
public class MyServlet extends BaseServlet {
```

Now for each request device will be detected and certain properties will be available. To gain access to these properties use:

```
getProperty(request,"PropertyName");
```

Where "PropertyName" is the name of the property you want to retrieve and request is the HttpServletRequest. Properties are returned as Strings. Full list of supported properties can be found on the [Property Dictionary](http://51degrees.com/Resources/Property-Dictionary) page. But for the purpose of identifying mobile device you can use:

```
boolean isMobile = Boolean.parseBoolean(getProperty(request,"IsMobile"));
```

The benefit of this particular solution is that regular expressions are not used in the detection process.